# idempotent matrix over local ring is similar to a diagonal matrix with elements $0$ and $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, local-rings

I want to know why any idempotent matrix $P$ over local ring is similar to a diagonal matrix with elements $0$ and $1$.

I saw a proof in [lemma 3.3 of ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+ring#KaplanskyTheorem), but I don't understand why $P$ is similar to a diagonal matrix if it has an invertible $r$-minor, and why such a matrix can be chosen with entries $0$ and $1$.

Could somebody explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$Let $V$ be the the underlying free module over the commutative local ring $A$ with unity.

Consider the submodules
$$
V_{0}
=
\Set{ v \in V : P v = 0},
$$
and
$$
V_{1}
=
\Set{ v \in V : P v = v}.
$$
Clearly $V_{0} \cap V_{1} = \Set{0}$.

For $v \in V$ one has
$$
v = (v - P v) + P v,
$$
where

- $v - P v \in V_{0}$, as $P (v - P v) = P v - P^{2} v = P v - P v = 0$, and
- $P v \in V_{1}$, as $P (P v) = P^{2} V = P v$.

Therefore $V = V_{0} \oplus V_{1}$, and $P$ is zero on $V_{0}$ and the identity on $V_{1}$.

---

**Addendum** The point of $A$ being local is that the direct summands $V_{0}, V_{1}$ are also free,